# How to dispatch async on the same thread for serial processing

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I run some lengthy synchronization task when the client receives a push notification. If 2 notifications arrive too quickly I get conflicts between the sync tasks as both try to enumarate and make changes in coredata.

How can I keep a reference to the queue and dispatch the next sync task to the same queue? Appologies for the question, but I am not good in plain C. Thank you.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    // I would need to keep reference to 'queue' so I can dispatch to it again with next push notification

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        [self.connection synchronizeWithLocal];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // make UI updates
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class can have a `dispatch_queue_t` property just like any other property.

```
@property (readwrite, assign) dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
```

Just assign the queue like you would assign any other property value.

```
self.myQueue = queue;
```

You don't want the queue you're using in that code, though. `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` is a global queue, which means that

- You don't need to save it in a property because it always exists (that's why "global" is in the function name).
- You don't want that queue for your purposes anyway because it's a concurrent queue, so it won't serialize operations. That queue is great for running multiple operations in parallel, which is exactly what you want to avoid.

It sounds like you need to create your own serial queue. Something like

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("my queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Then use that queue instead of a global queue. When you're done with it, make sure to clean it up using `dispatch_release`.

Comment: `dispatch_release` is not needed (and not allowed) under new versions of ARC; the property should just be strong.

Comment: @JesseRusak Agreed, but, technically, it's not a function of "version of ARC" or the version of the compiler, but rather depends upon your app's deployment target. If deployment target is less than iOS 6.0 (or if you use `-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0` compiler flag), then `dispatch_release` is required.

Comment: I am targetting iOS7 only and do use ARC obviously. So I will adjust the property accordingly and skip dispatch_release. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Thanks Jesse and Rob for the details.

Answer (score 3):

`dispatch_get_global_queue()` gives you a *concurrent* dispatch queue.
If you want a *serial* queue, you can create your own with:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and store that e.g. in a property of the application delegate.

However, if this is for doing Core Data operations, you better create a 
`NSManagedObjectContext` of the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and use its `performBlock:` method.